# webm video format doesnt play in firefox

Tags: asp.net, html, video, html5-video

i am trying to implement a video tag of html as

```
<video controls="controls" tabindex="5">
     <source src="Videos/2.webm" type="video/webm">
      <source src="Videos/2.ogv" type="video/ogg">
      <source src="Videos/2.mp4" type="video/mp4">

      </video>
```

the individual file of webm Plays into a firefox. but when i am integrating with my project it shows X sign. i have made the MIME type Implementation. what possible error is there. thanks for any assistance.

Comment: How have you tested your MIME type configuration?

Comment: @robertc No sir. how to test this?

Comment: Hit Ctrl+Shift+K and inspect the network events.

Comment: [17:18:31.102] HTTP "Content-Type" of "application/octet-stream" is not supported. Load of media resource http://localhost:52045/WebSite21/Videos/2.webm failed. @ http://localhost:52045/WebSite21/Default.aspx

Comment: @robertc sir it shows perticular error.

Comment: You've not configured your MIME types correctly on the server.

Answer (score 0):

What type of server your project resides on i.e. Apache server or anything else?
If it is Apache server, please try the following lines in your .htaccess file.

AddType video/mp4 .mp4
AddType video/ogg .ogv
AddType video/webm .webm